# Unable to install asurv

Tags: python-3.x, survival-analysis

I'm trying to install asurv, from https://github.com/rsnemmen/asurv.
For compilation, I use the given command,
gfortran -o asurv asurv.f

But I receive the following error,

```
asurv.f:6721:72:

 6721 |       IF(J.GT.97.OR.J.LT.1)PAUSE
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Deleted feature: PAUSE statement at (1)
asurv.f:1250:72:

 1250 |      +                   SWRK8,SWRK9,EWRK1,WRK8,MVAR)
      |                                                                        1
Error: Type mismatch in argument ‘nd’ at (1); passed REAL(8) to INTEGER(4)
```

Could not install asurv. There is probably something wrong with asurv.f